# How to use JetbrainsMono font in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, monospace

is there any way I can install Jetbrains Monospace font in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019?

Because Visual studio doesn't show the font in the list if available fonts and it doesn't offer an option to browse for/install it.

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio to offer you a font, it must be installed on your windows system. You can install the font through the Windows Settings screen. You can find the option to install fonts in the Personalisation section.

After installing the font in Windows, Visual studio should allow you to select it as your editor font.

See also:

- https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/install-fonts-on-windows-11

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Tools` -> `Options`

`Environment` group, `Fonts and Colors` item allows you to specify custom font for any of the display items.

I believe all of them are monospace.

Comment: Hi, i have tried but unfortunately there is no option for Monospace

Comment: @ask are you looking for a font named `Monospace`? Or just a mono-spaced font (NOT proportionally-spaced)? See http://home.myfairpoint.net/vzenu5ot/portfolio/sg_items/mono_propor_font_example.htm

Comment: I'm looking for Jetbrains Monospace font.

Comment: You can get it here https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/

Comment: okay, but how do i install it to Microsoft Visual studio?

Comment: Install it in windows from the Settings panel. Visual Studio will pick up all the fonts installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

- First, download the **JetBrains Mono** font from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/). You will get a .zip file from this site. Once unzipped, you may find a variety of fonts such as "Bold" and "Italic". Right-click on your favorite font and click "Install", and the font is installed.
- Open your Visual Studio, look at the menu bar, select "Tools" -> "Options" and find the font. After changing the fonts, you can **restart the IDE** to make the changes take effect.